# BigQuery dynamic declare variable to the table name?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

trying to figure out if I can declare a variable to then insert into part of the table name.

```
declare SiteLoc string default "04";

Select *
from FROM `gdw-prod-data.factory_04_data.YieldData`
```

How can I swap out the '04' in the from table to another location, like 07, 15, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#execute_immediate) for this.

```
declare SiteLoc string default "04";

EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE (
  'Select * from FROM `gdw-prod-data.factory_' || SiteLoc || '_data.YieldData`'
);
```

Comment: for the execute immediate, does it need to be all in a single line? I'm trying to make the query readable, and putting a 100 line query into a single line will be a pain.

Comment: Use triple quotes, these allow multiline content.

Comment: @surfer349 use `'''<query with line_separator's>'''` where line_separator is `\n`